# как удалить запись в колонке laravel?

Tags: laravel

ничего не удаляет
public static function destroy($idProduct)
{

```
       $product = Product::where('id', $idProduct)->first();
       $product->image = '';
       $product->save;
       
       return $idProduct;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
решение
public static function destroy($idProduct) 
    {
       
       $product = Product::where('id', $idProduct)->first();
       $product->image = '';
       $product->update();
       
       return $idProduct;
    }
```